# Oracle find a record based on a value in a string

Tags: oracle

I have the below two tables, I need to find a way to get the new_plan_id from table 2, based on the values found in table 1 Plan_ids value (15,25,1700).

I am using Oracle SQL developer, is this request possible?  If so how?  I'm not even sure what the syntax would start to look like.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Table_1

instance_id | var_name   | var_txt_value

22222 |         Plan_ids  |    15,25,1709

22222 |        Case_id     |  1245784544

22222 |        Client_id    | Company

table_2

old_plan_id  | old_plan_name | new_plan_id | new_plan_name

15|             plan_saver  |    2485       |   company_plan_saver

25 |            eco_plan     |   1425  |        company_eco_plan

1709|           gand_plan     |  7777    |      company_grand_plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to update table_1? Try below code,

```
BEGIN
    FOR tab2_rec IN (SELECT *
                       FROM table_2)
    LOOP
        UPDATE table_1
           SET var_txt_value = REPLACE(var_txt_value, tab2_rec.old_plan_id, tab2_rec.new_plan_id)
         WHERE var_name = 'Plan_ids';
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: YOU ROCK!!!!  Thank you!!!!  This worked perfectly!!!!  Thanks for sharing!